# Netbeans SVN E160006: No such revision

Tags: svn, netbeans, javahl

I apologize in advance for asking a question that is due to my being severely idiotic.. :)

Recently, I migrated my website hosting from one service to the other, including my databases and SVN repositories (I am not on a team, I am a self-employed contractor and I use SVN to do a backup of all the code I write).

Well, I messed up. And now I'm stuck. Brace yourself, this is pretty dumb.

1. I backed up my SVN repos with this SSH command `svnadmin dump path-to-repo | gzip > dumpfile.gz`
2. I did the domain migration
3. Re-loaded my SVN repos with this SSH command `gunzip -c home_dir/dumpfile.gz | svnadmin load svn/repository_id`
4. I did a "test commit" for each repo. Repo 1 wasn't working (some weird error), Repo 3 was.
5. I uninstalled/deleted all my repos and reinstalled them

Repo 1 still wasn't working, so I went to bed. Today, it works... So something probably just needed to flush in the system. HOWEVER...

Now, my local version of Repo 3 is "newer" than the online version, because I committed, deleted the online repo, and reinstalled it. Now the local version has a higher number than the online version, and Netbeans gives me this error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E160006: Commit failed (details follow):
E160006: No such revision 26
E175002: CHECKOUT of '/Proj3/!svn/ver/26/Proj3_test/src/mainpackage/Main.java': 500 Internal Server Error (http://www.mysite.com)
```

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

By deleting your subversion repository and recreating it you basically lost the entire history and started at the first revision. You working copy (local) is still at revision 26.

To sync with the sever you can just backup your working copy and do a fresh checkout from the server.

If you had no uncommited changes and everything works you can delete the (now old) working copy and continue working from revision 1 with the working copy you just checked out.

If you had uncommited changes then copy the changed files (or all files) over from the backed up old working copy (in explorer or on the cli) to the fresh checkout and commit.

Either way you won't be able to restore previous revisions since those were deleted together with the original repository.